# How do you run a proxy on a minecraft server?

Tags: proxy, hosting, java

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, and this is a highly specific question but maybe one of you are smart enough to help me work through it.

I've bought a virtual minecraft server through a hosting service called beastNode.

For a brief description on how the minecraft server works see here: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server

Well i'm trying to run a proxy in the form of a jar file on the server. For more info on how this normally works see here: 
http://mineshafter.appspot.com/instructions

The long and short is that the hosting service restricts my access to the server with a control panel so that I can really only edit files with FTP and start and stop the server. I'm assuming that clicking start in the panel simply runs the game jar. so I need it to run the proxy instead, any ideas?

I realize unless you run a server like this you probably have no idea what i'm talking about, and i'm sorry!

Comment: lol -1 me, I said it was highly specific, doesn't mean i don't REALLY need help with it.

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate for ServerFault. Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: @cody This site is for professional sysadmins. Unless you're making a professional Minecraft hosting business. Even then the question is still poorly formed, no documentation, no logs...

Answer (score 2):

Mineshafter is far from being a proxy at all, as far as i can see it's simply an illegal hacked copy of the regular server code. Not only does serverfault actively and consciously NEVER discuss or aid in illegal or morally dubious behaviour as a policy but SERIOUSLY dude, this is Minecraft, not EA, it's Notch and a handfull of decent inventive hardworking Swedes you're screwing over - grow a moral compass please.